# Custom ArrayAdapter. isEnabled does not update last item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have `ListView` and when the flag becomes false to disable part of the items. Let's say all except the first one. To make items visibly disabled I call `setAlpha()` in `isEnabled(position)` of adapter. This works good except that `isEnabled(position)` is not called for the last item if it is shown partially. And it happens only when I disable items. How can I force `ListView` to call it for ALL visible items?

What looks interesting that the last item is disabled, meaning that click on it do not cause `onClick` event. But it is not redrawn :(

I create items layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="0.12in"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:textSize="0.18in"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:text=">"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I initialize `ListView` in activity's `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    _cbChecked = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_checked);

    _isAllTestEnabled = true;

    final String[] itemsStrings =
            { "0. Item",
                "1. Item",
                "2. Item",
                "3. Item",
                "4. Item",
                "5. Item",
                "6. Item",
                "7. Item",
                "8. Item",
                "9. Item",
                "10. Item" };


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new BITAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.listText, itemsStrings);
    _listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    _cbChecked.setChecked(true);
    _cbChecked.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            _isAllTestEnabled = isChecked;
            _listView.invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

I wrote custom `ArrayAdapter`:

```
private class BITAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public BITAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        View child  = _listView.getChildAt(position - _listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        if (child == null) {
            return _isAllTestEnabled;
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            child.setEnabled(true);
            child.setAlpha(1.0f);
            return true;
        } else {
            child.setEnabled(_isAllTestEnabled);
            child.setAlpha(_isAllTestEnabled ? 1.0f : 0.3f);
            return _isAllTestEnabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you invalidate the listview  "_listView.invalidate()" ? , Instead of that you just notify the adapter.

Comment: How can I notify it?

Comment: you can notify by using "_listView.notifyDataSetChanged();"

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When I change `_listView.invalidate()` on `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` nothing changes - when I call it android does not ask is last visible item enabled

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem calling `isEnabled(_listView.getLastVisiblePosition())` in `OnItemClickListener` and saving enable state within the adapter:

```
 bitListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0) {
                bitAdapter.setEnabledState(!((CheckedTextView) view).isChecked());
                bitAdapter.isEnabled(bitListView.getLastVisiblePosition());
            }
        }
    });
```

and in `OnScrollListener`:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    bitAdapter.isEnabled(bitListView.getLastVisiblePosition());
}
```

This allows resolve missing `isEnabled()` invocation. Hope someone will save time :)